# The Lazy Loading property from entity is caming in findAll call

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm startinng study Spring Boot, and I have some doubts related to Lazy Loading use.

I have the **@PaymentEntity**, **@PaymentInstitutionEntity** and **@PaymentCustomerEntity**

PaymentEntity has a PaymentInstitution info and PaymentInstitution has a list of PaymentCustomers.

I have a controller **getAllPayments** to get all data from database, but I would like to not return PaymentCustomers list in this get method, so I added the **FetchType.LAZY** in paymentCustomers property, but when I test this implementation, the list of PaymentCustomers is caming. how do I make the list of paymentCustomer not appear in the getAll call?

follow my implementation below:

```
@Entity(name = "payment")
public class PaymentEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 20)
  private PaymentStatus status;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id", nullable = false)
  private List<PaymentInstitutionEntity> paymentInstitutions;
   
  // getters and setters implementation here
}


@Entity(name = "payment_institutuion")
public class PaymentInstitutionEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name = "payment_paying_institution_id", nullable = false)
  private List<PaymentCustomerEntity> paymentCustomers;
   
  // others columns implementation here
  // getters and setters implementation here
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/search-payments")
public ResponseEntity<List<PaymentDto>> getAllPayment() {

    final Pagination<PaymentDto> payments = paymentBO.getAll();
        
    return new ResponseEntity<>(payments.map(p -> paymentEntityConverter.convertToDto(p)),
        HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

BO

```
@Transactional
public Pagination<PaymentCanonical> getAll() {

  List<PaymentEntity> result = paymentEntityRepository.findAll();

  return pagination.map(p -> paymentEntityConverter.convertToEntity(p));        
}
```

NOTE: If I put the breakpoint in paymentEntityRepository.findAll(). the result is caming with list of paymentCustomer

Comment: Why are you not using any DTOs? And why can't you just remove the fields you are not using instead of using LAZY as the fetch type?

Comment: because it's a microservice, and it's will be used by a other microservice that need of this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You can try creating a new class which will be sent as the response of your API. You can choose the fields you need in the response, and then populate those fields accordingly from an object of `PaymentEntity`.

**Option 2:**
Or you can use a JPA Projection to only fetch the columns/fields you need and then return that as a response.

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Now, here's why using `FetchType.LAZY` won't do the job:
In simple terms JPA is running database queries internally. So, if you have associations(relationship) between two of your entities then it will fetch all the entities at once if you use `FetchType.EAGER`. However, if you use `FetchType.LAZY` then those entities will not be fetched until it is needed. It will only be fetched if you try to access that field.

You can think of this in this way:

Let's say you have two tables A and B, and two entity classes in your code EA and EB. You can have many EBs in an EA. If you use `FetchType.EAGER` then JPA is going to execute a query to fetch EA and all the EBs associated to it immediately(a join between A and B is executed). However, if you use `FetchType.LAZY` then only columns of A will be fetched (no join query with B), and all the associated Bs will only be fetched if you try to access any of the fields in EB via the object of EA.

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading