# Does findAll funtion of QuerydslPredicateExecutor join properies which has FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity like that structure:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "table1")
   public class XEntity implements Serializable {
   // Something something

   @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "x",
    cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Entity2> entity2List;
}
```

I don't want to join Entity2 in every query so I use `FetchType.LAZY` but when I call findAll funtion which come from QuerydslPredicateExecutor, it joins tables even predicate argument doesn't contain any condition about Entity2.

What is the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452344/the-lazy-loading-property-from-entity-is-caming-in-findall-call this?